# graphql resolving based on fields

Tags: graphql

Consider we have build a graphql server on top of a bunch of REST APIs and we have two endpoints, Industry and Company. We wrapped them all into the graphql server, which allows us to do query like following:

```
{industry (name: "Education") {companies {id}}}
```

It will give us:

```
{data: {industry:{companies: [{id:1}, {id:2}]}}}
```

A simple query.

If we ask more than that, let's say we ask for name of companies, it will return

```
{data: {industry:{companies: [{id:1, name: 'a'}, {id:2, name:'b'}]}}}
```

However, behind the screen, there is a big difference between those two queries. First one only ask for id, which industry end-point already provide it. The second one asks for name, which you have to make additional calls to company end-point to get it.

One way to do it, is to always send calls to company end-point, even though user only ask for ID, but I was thinking if we can make the resolver function aware which fields user is asking, and make more intelligent decisions.

I am not sure if this follow the best practice though. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you resolve this somehow?